# If phone number is not present in DCRM then create the lead records in dcrm else don't create the record in crm

Tags: javascript, plugins

I need to create lead records in DCRM using JS if lead phone number is not present in DCRM then create the lead record else don't create the lead records in DCRM.

Thanks,

Arshad

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am new in javascript but i tried to fetch xml and used but later i don't know how to processed with this.